# Set DelayValidation property using EzAPI

Tags: ssis, ezapi

I am using EzAPI to build an SSIS package.

FlatFileSource -> DerivedColumn -> ODBC Destination.

But I can't find where to set the Delay Validation property to true.  It's not letting me do so in the EzPackage or EzDataFlow objects.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, the DelayValidation property may be set for a FlatFileSource, but there is no DelayValidation property available for either a DerivedColumn component or an ODBCDestination.  On which object do you want to set the DelayValidation?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set it by casting the EzDataFlow object to a Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost object

```
EzDataFlow dataFlow = new EzDataFlow(Package);

((Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost)dataFlow).DelayValidation = true;
```